# GCC strange behaviour with full path include vs search path include

Tags: c, gcc, include

I've encountered GCC include behavior that I'm trying to understand.  The example I'm providing is the simplest test code, the actual code (and this behavior) are the result of a tool I'm using to instrument my code.  I **have** to use this tool.  I'm just trying to understand the reasons for getting the error.  Interestingly enough, g++ works fine.  Here's the example:

If I include `<sys/types.h>` everything compiles just fine, but if I include `"/usr/include/sys/types.h"` then I get an error.

Here's the error I get running the first `gcc` command below that includes the full path:

```
In file included from hello.c:7:
/usr/include/sys/types.h:195: error: redefinition of typedef ‘int8_t’
hello.c:5: error: previous declaration of ‘int8_t’ was here
```

Compiler command, using GCC 4.1.2 (CentOS 5) cause the error:

`gcc -g -I. --verbose -c -o hello.o -DLONG_INCLUDE hello.c`

or this one that does not cause the error

`gcc -g -I. --verbose -c -o hello.o hello.c`

Code:

```
/* hello2.h */

#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int myFunc(int *a);

#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif



/* hello.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef signed char int8_t;
#ifdef LONG_INCLUDE
#include "/usr/include/sys/types.h"
#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#endif
#include "hello.h"


int myFunc(int *a)
{

  if (a == NULL)
    return -1;

  int b = *a;

  b += 20;

  if (b > 80)
    b = 80;

  return b;
}
```

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

After looking at preprocessor output via `gcc -E` it looks like when specifying the full path, gcc does not treat it as a system include path and that, somehow, is contributing (causing?) the error.  Tries to use the `-isystem` option for `/usr/include` and `/usr/include/sys` but to no avail.

Comment: Probably unrelated: The macro is named `__cplusplus`. You are missing an underscore. Also, all this compiles fine on a non-ancient gcc.

Comment: @pmr Thanks, unfortunately, I'm stuck with the version of GCC and the dang tool.  At this point, I'm just trying to understand why does GCC treat it as a non-system header.

Comment: As you said,`isystem` seems to be the way to go here. I would wonder why you need to fully qualify the path in the first place. This seems a little... broken.

Comment: the tool is doing all of that and yeah, it's really broken.  What's strange is that `isystem` does not help

Comment: I got the same behaviour with gcc-4.5.1 (is that already ancient, @pmr?). Try setting `-D__int8_t_defined`, that guards the `int8_t` and friends typedefs in my `<sys/types.h>`.

Comment: @DanielFischer nice, thanks.  That worked.  You should post that as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm probably a minority but I consider everything that is not the current minor version ancient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Glibc's `<sys/types.h>`, the typedefs for `int8_t` etc. are guarded by

```
#if !__GNUC_PREREQ (2, 7)

/* These types are defined by the ISO C99 header <inttypes.h>. */
# ifndef __int8_t_defined
#  define __int8_t_defined
typedef char int8_t;
typedef short int int16_t;
typedef int int32_t;
#  if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef long int int64_t;
#  elif __GLIBC_HAVE_LONG_LONG
__extension__ typedef long long int int64_t;
#  endif
# endif
```

so a workaround for the problem would be to define the guarding macro on the command line, passing `-D__int8_t_defined` in addition to `-DLONG_INCLUDE`.